# How to filter through a JavaScript array using array.filter() method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I have a JavaScript Object (`filters`), which has boolean values. I also have an array of objects (`mainSubArray`). Based on the JavaScript `Object`, I want to return a new array (`filteredArray`) if the boolean values are true and not return a new array if the boolean value is false.

So far, I've tried the following:

```js
// The main array that needs to be filtered
const mainSubArray = [{
    MenB_Classification: "NOT Required",
    CONTROL: "Public",
    Enrollment: "892"
  },
  {
    MenB_Classification: "Required",
    CONTROL: "Private",
    Enrollment: "1601"
  },
  {
    MenB_Classification: "NOT Required",
    CONTROL: "Private",
    Enrollment: "447"
  },
  {
    MenB_Classification: "NOT Required",
    CONTROL: "Public",
    Enrollment: "1203"
  },
  {
    MenB_Classification: "Required",
    CONTROL: "Private",
    Enrollment: "32"
  },
  {
    MenB_Classification: "NOT Required",
    CONTROL: "Public",
    Enrollment: "98"
  },
  {
    MenB_Classification: "Recommended",
    CONTROL: "Private",
    Enrollment: "654"
  },
  {
    MenB_Classification: "NOT Required",
    CONTROL: "Private",
    Enrollment: "345318"
  },
  {
    MenB_Classification: "NOT Required",
    CONTROL: "Private",
    Enrollment: "13324"
  },
  {
    MenB_Classification: "Recommended",
    CONTROL: "Private",
    Enrollment: "39"
  },
  {
    MenB_Classification: "NOT Required",
    CONTROL: "Private",
    Enrollment: "4"
  },
  {
    MenB_Classification: "NOT Required",
    CONTROL: "Private",
    Enrollment: "910"
  },
  {
    MenB_Classification: "NOT Required",
    CONTROL: "Private",
    Enrollment: "23453"
  }
]


// Object with boolean values
var filters = {
  required: true,
  recomended: true,
  notRequired: false,
  publics: true,
  privates: true,
  ennrollmentOne: true,
  ennrollmentTwo: false,
  ennrollmentThree: false,
  ennrollmentFour: false,
}

// New Array using array.filter() method
var filteredArray = mainSubArray.filter(function(d) {
  if ((filters.required == true && d.MenB_Classification === 'Required') || (filters.recomended === true && d.MenB_Classification === 'Recommended') || (filters.notRequired === true && d.MenB_Classification === 'NOT Required') || (filters.publics === true && d.CONTROL === 'Public') || (filters.privates === true && d.CONTROL === 'Private') || (filters.ennrollmentOne === true && d.Enrollment < 100) || (filters.ennrollmentTwo === true && d.Enrollment >= 100 && d.Enrollment < 1000) || (filters.ennrollmentThree === true && d.Enrollment >= 1000 && d.Enrollment < 5000) || (filters.ennrollmentThree === true && d.Enrollment > 5000)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }

});

console.log(filteredArray);
```

When I `console.log(filteredArray)` , I get back the original array.

The output should be a new array that has only the values that are set to true in the `filters` object.

Comment: I tried your code and it looks original array mainSubArray  has 13 items , filtered array filteredArray  has 12 items inside , difference is {MenB_Classification: "NOT Required", CONTROL: "33033764030", Enrollment: "345318"}

Comment: what is `filters` doing? why it does not have vlaues who are directly comparable with the object's values?

Comment: What do you want the filtered array to look like? Right now I think the issue is with your logic, since you are using 9 or 10 different or statements it is almost always matching one of them. 

I would also suggest writing `someBoolean &&` instead of `someBoolean === true &&`.

Comment: Your if condition inside filter function covers everything and that's why you see the original array as result of filter

Comment: So, if **ANY** of the filters is true, include the item !? Or should it only include items where all filters apply?

Comment: Your code looks fine, seen as most records have `public` & `private` set, and your `filter` is asking for both of theses, makes sense that this rule alone is going to practically return all records.

Comment: @Thomas  I'm assuming a single record can't be both `public` and `private`, so that wound't seem to be the case.   The OP really needs to explain in more detail why he thinks this is wrong, because as it stands it looks perfectly fine.

Comment: @NinaScholz the ```filters``` is an object that is generated dynamically based on checkboxes. If the checkbox is clicked (or active), the corresponding value is set to true.

Comment: @Maria, the filtered array should basically be a new array derived from the main array. The thing i'm trying to achieve is to skip the current element if the filter object value is "false".

Answer (score 2):

You could take an array of strings for the keys of the filter object and according function for checking the wanted keys of the object with their wanted value/s.

In the filter function iterate key function array and exit early if a function is wanted and the result is `true`.

The result is an array of 12 object from original 13 objects.

```js
var data = [{ MenB_Classification: "NOT Required", CONTROL: "Public", Enrollment: "892" }, { MenB_Classification: "Required", CONTROL: "Private", Enrollment: "1601" }, { MenB_Classification: "NOT Required", CONTROL: "Private", Enrollment: "447" }, { MenB_Classification: "NOT Required", CONTROL: "Public", Enrollment: "1203" }, { MenB_Classification: "Required", CONTROL: "Private", Enrollment: "32" }, { MenB_Classification: "NOT Required", CONTROL: "Public", Enrollment: "98" }, { MenB_Classification: "Recommended", CONTROL: "Private", Enrollment: "654" }, { MenB_Classification: "NOT Required", CONTROL: "33033764030", Enrollment: "345318" }, { MenB_Classification: "NOT Required", CONTROL: "Private", Enrollment: "13324" }, { MenB_Classification: "Recommended", CONTROL: "Private", Enrollment: "39" }, { MenB_Classification: "NOT Required", CONTROL: "Private", Enrollment: "4" }, { MenB_Classification: "NOT Required", CONTROL: "Private", Enrollment: "910" }, { MenB_Classification: "NOT Required", CONTROL: "Private", Enrollment: "23453" }],
    filters = {
        required: true,
        recomended: true,
        notRequired: false,
        publics: true,
        privates: true,
        ennrollmentOne: true,
        ennrollmentTwo: false,
        ennrollmentThree: false,
        ennrollmentFour: false,
    },
    fn = [
        ['required', o => o.MenB_Classification === 'Required'],
        ['recomended', o => o.MenB_Classification === 'Recommended'],
        ['notRequired', o => o.MenB_Classification === 'NOT Required'],
        ['publics', o => o.CONTROL === 'Public'],
        ['privates', o => o.CONTROL === 'Private'],
        ['ennrollmentOne', o => o.Enrollment < 100],
        ['ennrollmentTwo', o => o.Enrollment >= 100 && o.Enrollment < 1000],
        ['ennrollmentThree', o => o.Enrollment >= 1000 && o.Enrollment < 5000],
        ['ennrollmentFour', o => o.Enrollment >= 5000]
    ],
    result = data.filter(o => fn.some(([k, f]) => filters[k] && f(o)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

It works, but your conditions cover almost all cases.

Even in your case it works as result contains 12 elements instead of 13.
It doesn't contain:

```
{
    MenB_Classification: "NOT Required",
    CONTROL: "33033764030",
    Enrollment: "345318"
  },
```

Comment: It is just confirmation that issue doesn't exist. Initial solution works fine. Other code is just to make it more elegant

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to do this:

```js
var data = [{ MenB_Classification: "NOT Required", CONTROL: "Public", Enrollment: "892" }, { MenB_Classification: "Required", CONTROL: "Private", Enrollment: "1601" }, { MenB_Classification: "NOT Required", CONTROL: "Private", Enrollment: "447" }, { MenB_Classification: "NOT Required", CONTROL: "Public", Enrollment: "1203" }, { MenB_Classification: "Required", CONTROL: "Private", Enrollment: "32" }, { MenB_Classification: "NOT Required", CONTROL: "Public", Enrollment: "98" }, { MenB_Classification: "Recommended", CONTROL: "Private", Enrollment: "654" }, { MenB_Classification: "NOT Required", CONTROL: "33033764030", Enrollment: "345318" }, { MenB_Classification: "NOT Required", CONTROL: "Private", Enrollment: "13324" }, { MenB_Classification: "Recommended", CONTROL: "Private", Enrollment: "39" }, { MenB_Classification: "NOT Required", CONTROL: "Private", Enrollment: "4" }, { MenB_Classification: "NOT Required", CONTROL: "Private", Enrollment: "910" }, { MenB_Classification: "NOT Required", CONTROL: "Private", Enrollment: "23453" }],
    filters = {
        required: true,
        recomended: true,
        notRequired: false,
        publics: true,
        privates: true,
        ennrollmentOne: true,
        ennrollmentTwo: false,
        ennrollmentThree: false,
        ennrollmentFour: false,
    },
    filteredArray = data.filter(function (d) {
      return ( // check MenB_Classification
           (filters.required && d.MenB_Classification === "Required")
        || (filters.recomended && d.MenB_Classification === "Recommended")
        || (filters.notRequired && d.MenB_Classification === "NOT Required")
      ) && ( // check CONTROL
           (filters.publics && d.CONTROL === "Public")
        || (filters.privates && d.CONTROL === "Private")
      ) && ( // check Enrollment
           (filters.ennrollmentOne && d.Enrollment < 100)
        || (filters.ennrollmentTwo && d.Enrollment >= 100 && d.Enrollment < 1000)
        || (filters.ennrollmentThree && d.Enrollment >= 1000 && d.Enrollment < 5000)
        || (filters.ennrollmentFour && d.Enrollment > 5000)
      );
    });

console.log(filteredArray);
```

Here a more verbose version. I've seperated the filter into one function for each property:

And I don't know wether this is relevant for you, but I've also added the case when there is no filter set for a property.

```
function filterByClassification(d){
    return (filters.required && d.MenB_Classification === "Required")
        || (filters.recomended && d.MenB_Classification === "Recommended")
        || (filters.notRequired && d.MenB_Classification === "NOT Required")
        // or no filter set for MenB_Classification
        || (!filters.required && !filters.recomended && !filters.notRequired);
}

function filterByControl(d){
    return (filters.publics && d.CONTROL === "Public")
        || (filters.privates && d.CONTROL === "Private")
        // or no filter set for CONTROL
        || (!filters.publics && !filters.privates);
}

function filterByEnrollment(d){
    return (filters.ennrollmentOne && d.Enrollment < 100)
        || (filters.ennrollmentTwo && d.Enrollment >= 100 && d.Enrollment < 1000)
        || (filters.ennrollmentThree && d.Enrollment >= 1000 && d.Enrollment < 5000)
        || (filters.ennrollmentFour && d.Enrollment > 5000)
        // or no filter set for Enrollment
        || (!filters.ennrollmentOne && !filters.ennrollmentTwo && !filters.ennrollmentThree && !filters.ennrollmentFour); 
}


filteredArray = data.filter(function (d) {
    // for every property, there must be one filter fulfilled
    return filterByClassification(d) 
        && filterByControl(d) 
        && filterByEnrollment(d);
});
```

while your code was equivalent to:

```
filteredArray = data.filter(function (d) {
    // if any condition at all is fulfilled, keep the item
    return filterByClassification(d) 
        || filterByControl(d) 
        || filterByEnrollment(d);
});`
```

Comment: I'm having difficulty figuring out the difference in our code and why your code worked and mine didn't. Anyway, thank you. This is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @NigelDcruz I was a bit in a hurry. I group the conditions by property. At least **one condition for each property** has to be `true`. Your code just asked if any condition was fulfilled. So if `filters.required` was fulfilled, it didn't care anymore about the filters for CONTROL or Enrollment.

Comment: @NigelDcruz I've added a more verbose example

Answer (score -1):

No, the filteredArray isn't same as main array. You can log the length to feel the difference easily.

Also, `if else` can be avoided to use a return on all condition only.

```js
// The main array that needs to be filtered
const mainSubArray = [{
    MenB_Classification: "NOT Required",
    CONTROL: "Public",
    Enrollment: "892"
  },
  {
    MenB_Classification: "Required",
    CONTROL: "Private",
    Enrollment: "1601"
  },
  {
    MenB_Classification: "NOT Required",
    CONTROL: "Private",
    Enrollment: "447"
  },
  {
    MenB_Classification: "NOT Required",
    CONTROL: "Public",
    Enrollment: "1203"
  },
  {
    MenB_Classification: "Required",
    CONTROL: "Private",
    Enrollment: "32"
  },
  {
    MenB_Classification: "NOT Required",
    CONTROL: "Public",
    Enrollment: "98"
  },
  {
    MenB_Classification: "Recommended",
    CONTROL: "Private",
    Enrollment: "654"
  },
  {
    MenB_Classification: "NOT Required",
    CONTROL: "33033764030",
    Enrollment: "345318"
  },
  {
    MenB_Classification: "NOT Required",
    CONTROL: "Private",
    Enrollment: "13324"
  },
  {
    MenB_Classification: "Recommended",
    CONTROL: "Private",
    Enrollment: "39"
  },
  {
    MenB_Classification: "NOT Required",
    CONTROL: "Private",
    Enrollment: "4"
  },
  {
    MenB_Classification: "NOT Required",
    CONTROL: "Private",
    Enrollment: "910"
  },
  {
    MenB_Classification: "NOT Required",
    CONTROL: "Private",
    Enrollment: "23453"
  }
]


// Object with boolean values
var filters = {
  required: true,
  recomended: true,
  notRequired: false,
  publics: true,
  privates: true,
  ennrollmentOne: true,
  ennrollmentTwo: false,
  ennrollmentThree: false,
  ennrollmentFour: false,
}

// New Array using array.filter() method
var filteredArray = mainSubArray.filter(function(d) {
  return ((filters.required && d.MenB_Classification === 'Required') || (filters.recomended && d.MenB_Classification === 'Recommended') || (filters.notRequired && d.MenB_Classification === 'NOT Required') || (filters.publics && d.CONTROL === 'Public') || (filters.privates && d.CONTROL === 'Private') || (filters.ennrollmentOne && d.Enrollment < 100) || (filters.ennrollmentTwo && d.Enrollment >= 100 && d.Enrollment < 1000) || (filters.ennrollmentThree && d.Enrollment >= 1000 && d.Enrollment < 5000) || (filters.ennrollmentThree && d.Enrollment > 5000));
});
console.log(mainSubArray.length)
console.log(filteredArray.length);
```

Comment: @TylerRoper Hey man, it wasn't an issue but a confusion instead. Suggestion of logging lengths on console is a solution to remove his confusion . :)